# Script not running in firefox addon build with KangoFramework

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, add-on, kango-framework

Ok so i am actually interested in building an extension for google chrome and firefox and my friend recommended me KangoFramework since it is cross platform.

So I downloaded ver 1.7.9 of the framework can't actually download ver 1.8.0 due to 404 error on their web or something. So I got to coding my first page with is the login page and I wrote some scripts for it to run and it work! Great !!

And so i wrote another page and I wrote another script and it works on google chrome but in firefox it seems like it didnt load my script at all as the debugger doesn't even show that I have the script file.

so i am confuse by this as how can this happen

here's my extension_info.json

```
    {
    "content_scripts": [
        "assets/Javascript/LoginPage.js"
    ], 
    "description": "Extension description", 
    "creator": "Annonymous", 
    "background_scripts": [
        "main.js"
    ], 
    "homepage_url": "http://kangoextensions.com/", 
    "version": "0.9.0", 
    "browser_button": {
        "caption": "some Extension", 
        "icon": "icons/Logo.png", 
        "tooltipText": "add on"
    }, 
    "name": "someExtension"
}
```

And here's my main.js File

```
function MyExtension() {
    var self = this;
    kango.ui.browserButton.addEventListener(kango.ui.browserButton.event.COMMAND, function() {
        kango.ui.browserButton.setPopup({url:'Index.html', width: 500, height:500});
    });
}

MyExtension.prototype = {

    _onCommand: function() {
        kango.browser.tabs.create({url: 'http://kangoextensions.com/'});
    }
};

var extension = new MyExtension();
```

and here's my html: http://pastebin.com/REdbhRqu

and here's my HamburgerMenu.js : http://pastebin.com/SvnRkH9Y

and lastly here the PhotoSwipe.js : http://pastebin.com/ykMW13YN

> PhotoSipe.js is just to start the plugin

Comment: Given that extensions can be written for both Chrome and Firefox (WebExtensions) that run *exactly* the same code, without the need for any translation, I'm not sure why you are starting a new project using a framework. It is likely that using the framework compiles into a Firefox Add-on SDK (or bootstrap) add-on. Those add-on types are deprecated and are scheduled to be removed from Firefox with version 57 on 2017-11-14. Only WebExtensions will be supported at that time, which are code-compatible with Chrome (with minor implementation differences, and most, but not all, APIs supported).

Comment: @Makyen so basically speaking code that can be compiled in chrome can also be compiled in firefox hence making kango framework pointless? with a few minor changes ??

Comment: Yes. I have multiple extensions (mostly code written for SO answers, testing, or of personal interest) which I have used, without any changes on both Firefox and Chrome. Some, with very limited functionality, I've also tested, again no code changes, on Opera and Edge (these get into some significant differences, but possible). As with any time that there are different implementations of similar APIs, there are differences in some details and what is supported on each. You will want to take a look at [Firefox WebExensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions).

Comment: At this point, unless there was a clear, very compelling, reason for using a framework like Kango, it would choose not to use it for a new project.

Comment: @Makyen ok thanks for the advise I will take heed to it.
Feel free to create an answer and i will accept it.

Comment: I appreciate the offer. While what I have stated is my opinion of the current situation with regard to browser extensions, it does not really answer the question you have written. The choice not to use Kango might make it such that an actual answer is not as valuable to your as was felt when you wrote the question. All-in-all, I'm not going to post an answer unless I have an answer for the actual question. Maybe someone else will have an answer for you.

Comment: @Makyen ok then